# Show that $X \sim Y$ implies $E[f(X)] = E[f(Y)]$ in any subset of $\Omega$

Tags: probability-theory

I know that given two identically distributed variables $X$, $Y$ and a measureable function $f$, the theorem holds when you integrate over the universe of events $\Omega$. However, I am not sure if it holds when you integrate over a smaller subset. Given a subset $A \subset \Omega$, I was trying to use the indicator function to change the probability of $X \in A$ with $Y \in A$, but the $|X|$ is still different from $|Y|$. Is it possible that the statement is false? Thanks for reading or giving any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

No, it is not the same over any set.  Imagine we roll two dice.  Let $X$ be the first outcome, $Y$ the second.  The outcomes are independent; they are
identically distributed, $X \sim Y$.

Of course (as noted) on the whole space
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[Y] = \frac{7}{2}
$$
Now consider this set:  $A = \{X = 1\}$.  Then
$$
\mathbb E[X\mathbf1_A] = 1\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{6},\qquad \mathbb E[Y\mathbf1_A] = \frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{7}{2} = \frac{7}{12} 
$$

Comment: Thanks for the example. I was trying to make the statement to be true to prove other theorem, but I was almost sure that doesn't work. Probably there might be some other conditions to make this possible.

Comment: Obviously that doesn't change anything, but you forget the factor $\frac{1}{6}=\mathbb P(A)$

Comment: @DominikKutek ... right, fixed.  I guess I was conditioning $\mathbb E[X | A]$ instead